# Getting 'Unresolved reference' for 'runOnUiThread'

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, android-runonuithread

While trying to save an image I am getting the error message *'Unresolved reference:runOnUiThread'* and also on the context terms inside the toast messages. The relevant code snippets are as below. I have tried all possible fixes, but failed. Please help!

```
private suspend fun saveDrawnView(myBitmap: Bitmap): String {
    var result = ""
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    if (myBitmap != null) {
        try {
            val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bytes)
            // val externalCacheDir = null
            val f = File(
                getExternalStorageDirectory()?.absolutePath.toString() +
                        File.separator + "com.example.drawingboardforkids" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + ".PNG"
            )
            val fo = FileOutputStream(f)
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray())
            fo.close()
            result = f.absolutePath
           runOnUiThread{
                if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(

                        this@MainActivity,
                        "File saved successfully :$result",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "Something went wrong while saving the file.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            result = ""
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    }
    return result
}

}
```

I've checked the coroutine dependencies inside build gradle, went throught clean, rebuild, invalidate caches, restart the pc etc., but the problem persists and hence the query. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem resolved. It occurred because the function was out of the scope of the MainActivity. Such a silly mistake..sorry for taking up the space and time.

Comment: we all make silly mistakes , Good Job !

Comment: Don't worry we all make mistakes around here :)